# Finding closest block range

Tags: c#, math, hex

I'm writing a library for a fileformat, that stores embedded files.

The space between the end of 1 file and the start of another isn't a fixed size. It's to the closest upper 0x1000. So for example, if File1 ended at 0xAC4654, File2 would start at 0xAC5000.

I can't think of a way to calculate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want to round up to the nearest 0x1000, then the following code should suffice:

```
Math.Ceiling((float)value / 0x1000) * 0x1000;
```

Comment: If you go above 2^23 bytes (8 MB) you loose precision. Use `((value - 1) | 0xFFF) + 1` instead.